# Mongoose not persisting returned object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongo: 3.2.1.

I have a model defined as such:

```
var MySchema = new Schema(
  {
    ....
    records: {type: Array, "default": []};
```

I first create an object based on that schema with no record field and it's correctly added to the database. I then update that object as such:

**Client**

```
angular.extend(this.object.records, [{test: 'test'}]);
this.Service.update(this.object);
```

**Server** (omitting the none-problematic code)

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    return updated.save()
      .then(updated => {
        console.log(updated);
        Model.find({_id: updated._id}).then((data)=> console.log(data));
        return updated;
      });
  };
}
```

The first console.log prints the object with records field updated. The second prints the object without. What am I missing? How can the resolved promise be different than the persisted object? Shouldn't  `data` and `updated` be identical?

Comment: `Object.find` ? Your model is named `Object` or I'm missing something?

Comment: It's not I just called it that way here to keep it simple but I now realised I made it confusing. I will edit

Comment: Did you try first to do the update and out of 'then' callback return the found object?

Comment: @LucasCosta I am not sure what you are asking? The `then(updated=>)` is called once the `.save()` is done and `updated` should be the new object but it's not. I try changing the names and a dozen other things but mongo just won't save the array of objects even though it's in the promise's resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple problems.

You are using the variable 'updated' twice.

```
var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);  // declared here
return updated.save()
  .then(updated => { // trying to re-declare here
```

The other issue might be that you are trying to merge the 'updates' property with the mongo object and not the actual object values.  Try calling .toObject() on your mongo object to get the data.

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    // call .toObject() to get the data values
    var entityObject = entity.toObject();
    // now merge updates values with the data values
    var updated = _.merge(entityObject, updates);
    // use findByIdAndUpdate to update
    // I added runValidators in case you have any validation you need
    return Model
      .findByIdAndUpdate(entity._id, updated, { 
        runValidators: true 
      })
      .exec()
      .then(updatedEntity => {
         console.log(updatedEntity);
         Model.find({_id: entity._id})
           .then(data => console.log(data));
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the first is an issue and in fact changing the variable name changes nothing. Using `findByIdAndUpdate` did fix my issue in fact I don't even need to merge the fields anymore.